# Magento 2 - get customer in collectRates()

Tags: magento2, table-rates

how can I get the customer in this code?

> magento/vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php

```
  public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        // exclude Virtual products price from Package value if pre-configured
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('include_virtual_price') && $request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                    $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
                }
            }
        }

        // Free shipping by qty
        $freeQty = 0;
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            $freePackageValue = 0;
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $freeShipping = is_numeric($child->getFreeShipping()) ? $child->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                            $freeQty += $item->getQty() * ($child->getQty() - $freeShipping);
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeShipping = is_numeric($item->getFreeShipping()) ? $item->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                    $freeQty += $item->getQty() - $freeShipping;
                    $freePackageValue += $item->getBaseRowTotal();
                }
            }
            $oldValue = $request->getPackageValue();
            $request->setPackageValue($oldValue - $freePackageValue);
        }

        if (!$request->getConditionName()) {
            $conditionName = $this->getConfigData('condition_name');
            $request->setConditionName($conditionName ? $conditionName : $this->_defaultConditionName);
        }

        // Package weight and qty free shipping
        $oldWeight = $request->getPackageWeight();
        $oldQty = $request->getPackageQty();

        $request->setPackageWeight($request->getFreeMethodWeight());
        $request->setPackageQty($oldQty - $freeQty);

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
        $rate = $this->getRate($request);

        $request->setPackageWeight($oldWeight);
        $request->setPackageQty($oldQty);

        if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
            $method = $this->_resultMethodFactory->create();

            $method->setCarrier('tablerate');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('bestway');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $freeQty) {
                $shippingPrice = 0;
            } else {
                $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($rate['price']);
            }

            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($rate['cost']);

            $result->append($method);
        } else {
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error $error */
            $error = $this->_rateErrorFactory->create(
                [
                    'data' => [
                        'carrier' => $this->_code,
                        'carrier_title' => $this->getConfigData('title'),
                        'error_message' => $this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'),
                    ],
                ]
            );
            $result->append($error);
        }

        return $result; 

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code into your model constructor

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    ...
}
```

Add below code in your function.

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request){
  ....
  echo $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
  ....
}
```